# Login - how to redirect to a page in a different espace?

Tags: outsystems

I have espace `backoffice` and other `layout`.  In the layout espace there is the Login default screen and I want to use this login screen and functionality in the backoffice espace. I added the login screen as a dependecy in the `backoffice` espace. And I have a link `Login` that has the destination this login web screen.

When the user clicks in the `login` link it goes to the login screen and after login with success he is redirected to the homepage that exists in the `layout` espace but I would like to redirect the user to the home page of the `backoffice` espace.

Do you know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the page where you came from using the `GetReferrerURL` server action from the HTTPRequestHandler` module. Note this can be empty when the navigation is not done trough a link.